# How to use code on React instructions homepage

Tags: node.js, reactjs

On the [React.js getting started page](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) to install with Node it says to do the following.

Install the react and react-dom packages. - **done and no errors**

Run: `npm install --save react react-dom babelify babel-preset-react`

**This worked fine**

**Then run....**

```
browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] main.js -o bundle.js
```

This gives me an error ( I've never used browserify ).

The error is that `main.js` isn't found.

Right above the instructions there is a random piece of code in a file named main.js....and it is just...well,  "sitting there" with no instructions what to do with it. So I assume that this is the file the last command is looking for.

So I copied the code to the node directory in a file named main.js and re ran: `browserify -t [ babelify --presets [ react ] ] main.js -o bundle.js`

This worked - no errors.

Now I have no idea what I am expected to do to see the "Hello world" text render. The way this "getting started" is written it infers the user should just magically know what to do at this point to see the example text render but I have no idea.

Note: I'm running express as a web server, and as a side note I am not being lazy, I seriously think these instructions are too partial and just bizarre. Below is what the "get started" gives you - minus the express web server.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO the "quickstart page" is not very helpful for a beginner:

in your project folder you will need the following files:

- package.json (generated by npm install ...)
- main.js (the javascript sample from the "quickstart" page)
- a file "bundle.js" which is generated by the "browserify" command
- an index.html with the following contents

`<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body> 
        <div id="example"></div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>

    </body>
    </html>`

You can see your results by opening the index.html in your browser...

Comment: Thanks, the problem is they assume the reader has experience with browserfiy - which is a poor move on their technical writer dept part.